# Is $R=\{a+b\rho : a,b \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is $R=\{a+b\rho : a,b \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ a ring where $\rho=e^{2\pi i/5}$?

Since $R$ is a subset of the complex numbers we only have a few axioms to check. All but one of these are trivial (to me) but I can't seem to prove whether $xy \in R$ for all $x,y \in R$. Taking two arbitrary elements of the ring and multiplying gives $ac+bd\rho^2+(ad+bc)\rho$ which I'm not sure is in $R$ or not. I tried come up with a relation and got $\rho^5-1=0$ so I don't think I can get rid of the $\rho^2$ term.

So is it not a ring then?

Is this a valid counter example $\rho^2=e^{4\pi i/5} \notin R$.

Comment: Yes, it is...of you can prove that $\;\rho^2$ doesn't have the general form of an element in $\;R$ .

Comment: Solve $a + b \rho = \rho^2$ for coefficients $a,b \in \Bbb R$, and find a *unique* solution.  Note that in this solution, $a$ and $b$ are not integers.

Comment: What do you mean to solve that equation?

Comment: @DonAntonio "It is"?

Comment: That "of" there should have been an "if"...oh, well. And then yes: it *would* be a valid counter example.

Comment: How do you solve $a+b\rho=\rho^2$ for $a,b$?

Comment: @Sammy A geometric picture of the problem others are getting at with solving $a+b\rho$:  Look in the complex plane: $\rho^2$ does not lie on the lattice of points generated by $1$ and $\rho$, which is what you get if you are looking at $a+b\rho$ for integers $a,b$.

Answer (score 2):

$$a+b\rho=\rho^2\implies \rho^2-b\rho-a=0$$

The above means $\;\rho\;$ is a root of the real (or integer, in fact) polynomial $\;x^2-bx-a\;$, and thus also $\;\overline\rho\;$ is a root, and then

$$\rho\overline\rho=-a\;,\;\;\rho+\overline\rho=b$$

Check the above implies

$$b=\rho+\overline\rho=2\,\text{Re}\,\rho=2\cos\frac{2\pi}5$$
and also

$$-a=\rho\overline\rho=|\rho|^2=1$$

but $\;=2\cos\frac{2\pi}5\notin\Bbb Z\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

$R$ is not a ring because it is not stable for multiplication. In fact 
$$0+1\rho=\rho\in R$$ but $$(\rho)^2=(\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{5})^2=\cos\frac{4\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{4\pi}{5}\text{ (Moivre) }$$
In other words $$\rho=\cos 72^{\circ}+i\sin72^{\circ}\text { but } \rho^2=-\cos 36^{\circ}+i\sin36^{\circ}\notin R$$